# Laravel Dusk - get textarea element by attribute and type text

Tags: laravel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel Dusk and I have this HTML at one page:

```html
<div>
    <textarea class="" data-auto="notes" style="height: 72px;"></textarea> 
    <button class="">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 9.877141 7.3747067" height="7.375" width="9.877"> 
            <path d="M8.517 0a.56.56 0 0 0-.397.166L3.896 4.418l-2.14-2.14a.56.56 0 0 0-.796 0l-.795.794a.56.56 0 0 0 0 .795l2.53 2.53c.005.005.006.012.011.017l.795.795.002.002c.22.219.576.218.795-.002l5.416-5.455A.561.561 0 0 0 9.712.96L8.917.164h-.002A.561.561 0 0 0 8.517 0z" ></path> 
        </svg>
    </button>
    <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

How I can type text into the text-area and click on the button? There is no name, no class, no ID... only attribute...

I try:

```php
$browser->element("textarea[data-auto='notes']")->type('some notes');
$browser->element("/button/svg")->click();
$browser->pause(1000);
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: What is the exact _Locator Strategy_ are you using? `textarea[data-auto='notes']` suggests Css where as `/button/svg` xpath

Answer (score 5):

Use `keys()` instead of `type()`:

```php
$browser->keys('textarea[data-auto="notes"]', 'some notes');
```

Use `click()` and a valid CSS selector:

```php
$browser->click('button');
```

Comment: yes but its not only button in the page $browser->click('button');

Comment: Do the button's parents have classes or ids?

Comment: We need some way to uniquely identify the button. Do the other buttons have an `svg` element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195221/discussion-between-aleks-per-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding your own selector?

```html
<button dusk="my-button"></button>
```

Then in Dusk:

```php
$browser->click('@my-button');
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk#interacting-with-elements

Otherwise, you can always get the selector by right clicking the element in the developer console, but I would not recommend doing that.

[image: Copying the selector from the developer console]
*(source : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4550#issuecomment-500177115)*

Comment: because I don't have access to original content - not my website, I use it to check prices